# how to debug in rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am running the the rspec case and I want to print some objects on the terminal while running   rspec.how to this.thanks in advance

I am using old version of rails and running by this command
script/spec spec/

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to put `puts` calls in your specs. There is no reason why this would not work

Comment: like suppose if /i have object called person so in that case "puts person" should work